# Header HTML getting moved depending if it's on mobile or laptop

Tags: html, css, header

[This is how it looks on computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMIOW.png)

And this is how it looks on the phone

[how it looks on the phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw3Fi.png). However, if I centered it on the computer, it becomes indented on the phone and vicersa.

My question is how can I get it to be centered on both big and small screens?

Here's the link of the site: https://website-eight-self.vercel.app/

These are the relevants files both CSS and HTML. Thank you so much and I hope you can help me.

```css
header {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
      <header>
      <Link href="/">
       <a>Juan David Campolargo</a>
      </Link>
      </header>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got which is your desired result. Could you please clarify your question?
Also, are you using any CSS framework or you're trying to achieve responsive behaviour with just pure CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **@media** to **target specific range of screen/device!**

**Adjust the margin** in **Phone Version/Small Screens**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  header {
    margin-left: ;
    margin-top: ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Fixed it. Follow up. How can I make so it goes aligned with the about twitter email ... no matter the device? Thank you again, Sagmar!

Comment: Set margin left  and right to auto, and set width!  It will be responsive to all the screens phone or pc

Comment: auto? what do you mean by set width? Do you have an example?

Comment: Example in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

To set the alignment auto across all devices/screens use **margin** and **width**
Code below

```
#Sample{
Width: 90%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you much!! Another quick question. When you are using an image on markdown <Image src="/images/walkway.png" width={600} height={400} />. Is there a way to have the height/width automatically instead of me guessing the right proportions?